# jquery popup box keyboard access only

Tags: jquery, popup, focus

Hi im testing a mvc3 website so that it can be accessed by using only the keyboard.

My problem is I have a jquery popup box with options to click but the only way to access them is to click on the box and then you can use the keybored.

Is there a way of automaticly getting focus on the popup with out clicking it.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of jquery popup are you using? jQuery UI dialog? BlockUI? Can we see your code for creating the popup?

Answer (score 0):

jquery:

```
$(element).focus();
```

this set the focus to the given element